# Addressing the lack of Discriminator support in Hibernate with InheritanceType.JOINED for legacy database

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa

A number of the responses and the various Hibernate open JIRA tickets linked in the answers  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4275517) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7988756) all indicate that attempting to use an `InheritanceType.JOINED` strategy with `@DiscriminatorColumn` and `@DiscriminatorValue` (as illustrated below) won't work. See specifically: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6911.

My scenario is that I have a legacy database that uses a standard "type" table to distinguish among a number of concrete types for an abstract type, with referential integrity constraints enforcing alignment. It seemingly would require the Discriminator field on the abstract type to be set correctly in order for the JPA model to faithfully represent the intent of the database model. A simplified version of the tables are as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CONTACT_INFORMATION (
    CONTACT_INFORMATION_ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FK_STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE_ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    -- more here...
    PRIMARY KEY (CONTACT_INFORMATION_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE (
    STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE_ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CONTACT_INFO_TYPE_CD CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION_TX VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE POSTAL_ADDRESS (
    FK_CONTACT_INFORMATION_ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    -- more here...
    PRIMARY KEY (FK_CONTACT_INFORMATION_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ELECTRONIC_ADDRESS (
    FK_CONTACT_INFORMATION_ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    -- more here...
    PRIMARY KEY (FK_CONTACT_INFORMATION_ID)
);
```

There are referential integrity constraints from `ELECTRONIC_ADDRESS` and `POSTAL_ADDRESS` to `CONTACT_INFORMATION`, and one from `CONTACT_INFORMATION` to `STND_CONTACT_INFORMATION_TYPE`.

Attempting to create JPA-annotated entities that would let me work with this model, I came up with the following:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT_INFORMATION")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "FK_STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE_ID", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class ContactInformation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CONTACT_INFORMATION_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private StandardContractInformationType contactInformationType;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE")
public class StandardContractInformationType  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "CONTACT_INFO_TYPE_CD", nullable = false)
    private String typeCode;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION_TX", length = 30)
    private String description;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "POSTAL_ADDRESS")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "FK_CONTACT_INFORMATION_ID")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
public class PostalAddress extends ContactInformation { /*...*/ }

@Entity
@Table(name = "ELECTRONIC_ADDRESS")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "FK_CONTACT_INFORMATION_ID")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "2")
public class ElectronicAddress extends ContactInformation { /*...*/ }
```

Note that even this implementation requires hard-coding the discriminator values of '1' and '2' corresponding to the reference data that's pre-loaded into the `STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE` table for the two subtypes.

With this implementation, and using Hibernate 4, inserting a record for either PostalAddress or ElectronicAddress does not properly set the FK_STND_CONTACT_INFO_TYPE_ID field for the abstract base table, as per the issues identified in the earlier questions.

So, after all that, the question is: what options are available to keep working with a nice JPA model while still trying to be faithful to the intent of the original database model? Try out a different provider? Do a lookup of the standard type info and add the enforcement up in a Repository or Service layer? Try squinting real hard and look at this as a composition problem instead of an inheritance one?