# Table Per Type - Making a Custom Join Formula in Hibernate / JPA?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Consider the following SQL tables using a Table Per Type inheritance pattern:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
  name VARCHAR(50),
  address VARCHAR(50),
  is_faculty BOOLEAN,
  age SMALLINT NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY(name, address, is_faculty)
);

CREATE TABLE student (
  name VARCHAR(50),
  address VARCHAR(50),
  current_grade SMALLINT,

  PRIMARY KEY(name, address)
);

CREATE TABLE faculty (
  name VARCHAR(50),
  address VARCHAR(50),
  department VARCHAR(2)

  PRIMARY KEY(name, address)
);
```

Obviously the idea here is that if, for example, I wanted to get a faculty member, I'd use the following join formula:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM person
  INNER JOIN faculty
    ON person.name = faculty.name
    AND person.address = faculty.address
    AND person.is_faculty = true;
```

Now consider the following Hibernate entities representing said tables:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@IdClass(PersonId.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "address", length = 50)
    private String address;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "is_faculty")
    private boolean isFaculty;

    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
    private int age;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public class PersonId implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private boolean isFaculty;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, hashCode, equals, etc.
}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "address", referencedColumnName = "address"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "is_faculty", referencedColumnName = "is_faculty"),
})
public class Student extends Person {
    @Column(name = "current_grade")
    private int currentGrade;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

```java
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "faculty")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "address", referencedColumnName = "address"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "is_faculty", referencedColumnName = "is_faculty"),
})
public class Faculty extends Person {
    @Column(name = "department", length = 2)
    private String department;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

There's a clear problem here however; the `faculty` and `student` tables have no `is_faculty` column. But we still need to join on either `true` or `false` for `is_faculty`, as shown in the SELECT statement above.

Normally, this would be solved by using `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas` / `@JoinColumnOrFormula` with `@JoinFormula` and `@JoinColumn` if this weren't an inheritance based join. However, to my knowledge no such alternative exists, such as `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumnsOrFormulas`.

My workaround so far has been to just add an `is_faculty` column to the `faculty` and `student` tables, so that both tables share the exact same composite PK columns (letting Hibernate join them using `PersonId`).

Comment: 2 question: *what exactly are you trying to do?* and *are you in control of the schema?* It seems that what you actually want is a `Person` base entity with 2 child entities, `Student` and `Faculty`. Do you really need to reflect this inheritance in the DB? If so and if you are in control of the schema, you can change the `is_faculty` to `person_type` and make it a discriminator column (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275517)). Also, I feel that `isFaculty` should not be part of the PK.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Crap, that's right, `Student` and `Facility` are both child entities, I just forgot to add `extends Person` to `Faculty`. On that note, I am in control of the schema, but these tables are just simplified examples to reproduce my problem, and not my actual schema; in this case, `is_faculty` has to be part of the primary key.

I think you may be onto something there with the discriminator + secondary table, I'm gonna have to check that out. Thanks.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos using `@SecondaryTable` and a discriminator column didn't work in this situation, since the discriminator column (`is_faculty`) is part of the composite key (`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: The '@JoinColumn' for a secondary table must reference the primary key`)

Comment: @TwistedTea Are you able to change the primary key structure? I.e. just a single attribute like an Id? You still could use `is_faculty` as discriminator. E.g.  `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` and `@DiscriminatorColumn(name="is_faculty", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.BOOLEAN)` on the `Person` entity.
If that suits you, I might be able to write an answer :)

Comment: @J.M.Arnold sorry, a single primary key just doesn’t make sense in my exact situation. the discriminator needs to be part of the composite primary key in the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

If the discriminator must be part of the composite primary key, then your initial workaround is a reasonable approach given the constraints of Hibernate and SQL. You can add the `is_faculty` column to both the `student` and `faculty` tables, and ensure that they are set to `true` or `false` accordingly.

You may still encapsulate this logic within your application, ensuring that the column is managed transparently and the correct value is always used:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "address", referencedColumnName = "address"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "is_faculty", referencedColumnName = "is_faculty"),
})
public class Student extends Person {

    @Column(name = "current_grade")
    private int currentGrade;

    @Column(name = "is_faculty", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private boolean isFaculty = false;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "faculty")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "address", referencedColumnName = "address"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "is_faculty", referencedColumnName = "is_faculty"),
})
public class Faculty extends Person {

    @Column(name = "department", length = 2)
    private String department;

    @Column(name = "is_faculty", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private boolean isFaculty = true;

    // Constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

The `insertable = false, updatable = false` attributes make it clear that the application will not directly modify these values, and you can set the values in your constructors or setters, as needed.

Comment: I appreciate the acknowledgement that this is probably the best approach given Hibernates current state, but this belongs as a comment, not an answer.